# Flexbox and :nth-child are not being rendered properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make 4 boxes, of which first 2 are green, and the content (one font-awesome icon and one `<p>` should be centered vertically.

```css
.big-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 .big-div:nth-child(-n + 2) {
    background-color: green;
 }
.small-div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="big-div">
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>    
    <p>Number 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    <p>Number 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    <p>Number 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    <p>Number 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried and tried but I can't make it work. Is there a problem in my code?

Comment: You’re applying nth-child to the wrong element ... you only have one single `.big-div` element, the `.small-div` elements are the ones of which you want to format the first two differently ...

Comment: `:nth-child(-n + 2)` selects the `.big-div` that is the -n+2nd child, not it's content. It should be `.small-div:nth-child(-n + 2) `

Comment: also maybe not use n-th child with an expression when you really want 2 specific childs to have that effect. What if you add a third box for instance? want it to be green as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `nth` on wrong element it should be used like this `.big-div div:nth-child(-n + 2)`. Your code:

```css
.big-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 .big-div div:nth-child(-n + 2) {
    background-color: green;
 }
.small-div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="big-div">
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>    
    <p>Number 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    <p>Number 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    <p>Number 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    <p>Number 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solution is missing the request for vertical alignment of the text and icon.

Comment: very nice (never downvoted you in the first place but here have an upvote!)

Comment: Why is `justify-content: center;` a solution? I thought it was only for horizontal alignment

Comment: @Al-josh When you change `flex-direction`  to `column` then justify-content and align-items basically swap roles. Just try to imagine it and it will be easier to understand :)

Comment: @Al-josh Also you should choose one of answered solutions so people can know this one is solved.

Answer (score 2):

You should change `big-div:nth-child` to `small-div:nth-child`
And for `small-div` you need `justify-content: center`

```css
.big-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 .small-div:nth-child(-n + 2) {
    background-color: green;
 }
.small-div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="big-div">
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>    
    <p>Number 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    <p>Number 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    <p>Number 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    <p>Number 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **`justify-content: center;`** for vertical center in **`.small-div`**.

And your **`nth-child`** is not working because you are applying it wrong.

You have to apply it on the child element **`.small-div`**

Change **`.big-div:nth-child(-n + 2)`** to **`.big-div .small-div:nth-child(-n + 2)`**

```css
.big-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.big-div .small-div:nth-child(-n + 2) {
  background-color: green;
}

.small-div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="big-div">
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>Number 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>Number 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>Number 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>Number 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the nth-child you need to do it on `.small-div`

```
.big-div .small-div:nth-child(-n + 2) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

and to have the elements inside you div be center vertically you need to :

```
align-content: center;
```

Because `align-items: center;` is when you have only one line of elements side by side, and align-content is to use when you have 2 elements or more under each others.

```css
.big-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

 .big-div .small-div:nth-child(-n + 2) {
    background-color: green;
 }

.small-div {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="big-div">
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>    
    <p>Number 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    <p>Number 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    <p>Number 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-div">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    <p>Number 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```